# iTerm2 v3: "Color tab labels on activity" disappeared?

Tags: iterm2

iTerm2 [general usage docs](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-general-usage.html) do mention "Color tab labels on activity", but I can't find it under the Preferences>Appearance . I really liked that colorization feature, "Show tab activity indicators" is too annoying with that spinner.

Running build 2.9.20160206.